# Upgrading Django, how to get manage.py

Tags: django, upgrade

I am looking to upgrade from Django 1.5 to 1.6.

So I have set up a virtualenv, downloaded everything that was in my pip freeze (but changed the Django version).

I tried

```
python manage.py runserver
```

but I am getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_manager
ImportError: cannot import name execute_manager
```

A google tells me this is because execute_manager has gone in Django 1.6. But my manage.py file is from a few versions back (1.3 probably).

Is there a preferred way to upgrade the manage.py?

That gets put there when you run startproject. Should I just look in  the Django package for an up to date manage.py? Or is there a preferred way to upgrade? Is there anything else that needs copied / changed at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this http://talks.caktusgroup.com/shipit/2013/django16-upgrade-experience/#/ and see the release note https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/ of django 1.6 where everything is mentioned about the changes. you may need to arrange your manage.py according to the changes made for django 1.6